# Factor Theorem and Long Division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For instance

Given $f(x) = 2x^3-7x^2+2x+3$, and $(x-3)$ is one of the factors, how do I obtain $2x^2-x-1$ as the quotient without using the long division. Is there any other method apart from long division?

Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you need to find?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid long division ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust-What is the meaning of obtaining $2x^2-x-1$ as the quotient?

Comment: This is a quite different question !

Comment: Answer: Compare the leading coefficients and check that $$f(1)=f(-1/2)=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Although there's already an answer linking to the method known as *Ruffini's Rule*, I detail its computation below, because it was very popular when I was in high school. It enables us to find **easily** the division of a polynomial by a linear term of the form $ x-x_0 $, even when the remainder $r(x)$ is not equal to $0 $. In your case $ x_0=3 $ and $r(x)=0$.

You want to find the unique second degree polynomial $ g (x) $ satisfying

$$\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}=\frac{2x^3-7x^2+2x+3}{x-{\color{blue}3}}=g (x).$$

Its coefficients can be found by [*Ruffini's Rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule). Applied to this division it consists of the following algorithm:

\begin{array}{c|rrrl}
&  x^{3} & x^{2} & x^{1} & \phantom{-} x^{0}   \\ 
& 2 & -7 & 2 & \; \; \phantom{-}3 &\to \text{  coefficients of } f (x) \\
   x_0={ \color{blue}3} & \downarrow & 6 & -3 & \;\;-3 \\
              &    & {\color{gray}{=}}{\; \color{blue}3}{\color{gray}{\cdot 2}} &  {\color{gray}{=}}{\; \color{blue}3}{\color{gray}{ (-1)}} &  {\color{gray}{=}}{\; \color{blue}3}{\color{gray}{ (-1)}} \\
    \hline  & 2 & -1 & -1 & |\phantom {-}{\color{green}0}&\to \text{  coefficients of } g (x) \text{ and }{\color{green}{\text{remainder}}} \\
   & & { \color {gray} {=-7+6 } } &  { \color {gray}{=2-3} }  & | {   \color {gray}{=3-3 }} \\
 &  x^{2} & x^{1} & x^{0} & |\color{green}{\text{remainder}}
    \end{array}

which confirms that

\begin{equation*}
g(x)=2x^{2}-x-1.
\end{equation*}

ADDED. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1388160/752) answer I've posted another example of the application of Ruffini's rule.

Comment: YES YES!!! THis is the ONE!!!  THanks a Million! Tavares!!

Comment: Even synthetic division is not the same as yours, synthetic division is more like long division.   :-)

Comment: So let me confirm, suppose we have found the zero which is 3 in this case, is that always true that the last term x^0 has a coefficient of 0?

Comment: @user256670 In general, no. The last term (in the same line  of the coefficients of $g(x)$) is the remainder, which in this case is $0$, but in general wouldn't be. Given the numerator $f(x$) and the denominator $x-x_0$ it finds the coefficients of $g(x)$ and the remainder $r(x)$, i.e. $f(x)=g(x)(x-x_0)+r(x)$. In your case $r(x)=0$

Comment: Understood. It is just a special case when it equals to zero so to speak.
Great!! Much thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the process of long division by a linear factor using an algorithm known as synthetic division, also called Ruffini's Rule. You are working only with coefficients here plus you are dealing with addition rather than subtraction, which tends to be easier.

You can read more here:

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule

Comment: That's right, I think it is the that I am looking for.  Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up and solve simultaneous questions.

You know that $2x^3-7x^2+2x+3$ will factorise as follows:

$$2x^3-7x^2+2x+3 \equiv (x-3)(ax^2+bx+c)$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants you need to find. If you expand the right-hand side you get

$$2x^3-7x^2+2x+3 \equiv ax^3+(b-3a)x^2+(c-3b)x-3c$$

Comparing coefficients gives: $a=2$, $b-3a=-7$, $c-3b=2$ and $-3c=3$. You need to solve these simultaneously. It's clear that $a=2$ and $c=-1$ so we get $b=-1$ and hence

$$2x^3-7x^2+2x+3 \equiv (x-3)(2x^2-x-1)$$

I would *recommend* that you try to master long division. It is much easier when, for example, you are dividing a quartic by a quadratic and there is a remainder. For easy questions, the method above is fine, but for more complicated ones, division is the way to go.

Comment: I am sorry to ask the questions without being intelligent. What happened was I missed my math class today.  My classmate told me our math lecturer taught the class a method by manipulating the coefficients and the index of each term in the polynomial as a quickies without doing long division.

After reading your explanations, I guess this is the thing I am looking for.

Many thanks!

Comment: @user256670 This does seem to be the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To divide a polynomial $P(x)$ by another $D(x)$, you need to find a third polynomial $Q(x)$ such that

$$P(x)=D(x)\times Q(x),$$ where the $\times$ denotes the product of polynomials. From this relation, we see that the degree of $P$ equals the sum of the degrees of $D$ and $Q$.

It turns out that in general this factorization is impossible, as is the case with integers. Anyway, the situation can be also rescued by considering a remainder polynomial $R(x)$ such that

$$P(x)=D(x)\times Q(x)+R(x),$$ and the degree of $R$ is smaller than that of $D$.

In the special case that $D(x)=x+a$, a binomial of the first degree, we have that the degree of $Q$ must be one less than that of $P$ and the degree of $R$ is $0$ ($R$ is a constant.)

---

The most efficient and easy way to obtain $Q$ is by long division.

Answer (score 0):

Put

$$g(x) = \frac{2x^3 -7 x^2 + 2 x + 3 }{x-3}$$

To write $g(x)$ explicitly as a quadratic polynomial (where you remove the removable singularity at $x = 3$) can then be done in many different ways, long division, or equating it to an undetermined quadratic and solving for the coefficients as in Fly by Night's solution, or series expansion around x = infinity is equivalent to synthetic division mentioned by Deepak.

Another method is to use use Lagrange interpolation to find the quadratic polynomial. You then evaluate $y_i = g(x_i)$ at 3 different points $x_i$. You can then write:

$$g(x) = \sum_{i} y_{i}\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$$

Comment: We are currently through the chapter of Remainder Theorem and Factor Theorem. And our lecturer told the class about a 'less authentic' method meaning method other than long division which now as I recall from what my classmate told me, resembles Fly by Night's solution.

It's like a quickies that you can follow the coefficients and index of the corresponding x term.

I am going to organize things a bit using what Fly by Night explained to me.  Again, how silly of me to have missed that, I should have been generalized the Q(x) as a quadratic. The class is so far confined to x cube only.
THANKS!